# _Scraping_ using Beautiful Soup from a Forum - How to scrape Tables which are repeated multiple times with <td>?

Tags: python, html, css, selenium, beautifulsoup

I want to scrape table data from a Forum which requires to login using a username and a password. I have written my code but cannot get any values from the forum table. Here is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

URL = 'http://kingmedia.tv'
LOGIN_ROUTE = '/home/'

HEADERS = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.125 Safari/537.36', 'origin': URL, 'referer': URL + LOGIN_ROUTE}

s = requests.session()


login_payload = {
        'login': "bachoo786",
        'password': "abcde12345" 
        }

login_req = s.post(URL + LOGIN_ROUTE, headers=HEADERS, data=login_payload)

print(login_req.status_code)

cookies = login_req.cookies


soup = bs(s.get(URL + '/forumdisplay.php?f=2').text, 'html.parser')
tbody = soup.find('table', id='tborder')
print(tbody)
```

I also tried using selenium but cannot get the data. Here is my selenium code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options 
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC 
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
#from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

URL = 'http://kingmedia.tv'
LOGIN_ROUTE = '/home/'

HEADERS = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.125 Safari/537.36', 'origin': URL, 'referer': URL + LOGIN_ROUTE}

s = requests.session()


login_payload = {
        'login': "bachoo786",
        'password': "abcde123" 
        }

login_req = s.post(URL + LOGIN_ROUTE, headers=HEADERS, data=login_payload)

print(login_req.status_code)

cookies = login_req.cookies


options = Options()
# Runs Chrome in headless mode.
#options.add_argument("--headless") 
#path of the chrome driver
chrome_options = Options() 
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless") 
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox') 
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage') 
driver=webdriver.Chrome('/usr/bin/chromedriver', chrome_options=chrome_options) 
driver.headless=True 
driver.get('http://kingmedia.tv/home/forumdisplay.php?f=2') 
WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'div.sidebar-widget.widget_text>div>table'))) 
print("Data rendered successfully!!!")
#Get the page source
html = driver.page_source 
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')

#print (soup)

driver.close() 
table=soup.find('table' , class_='tborder').find_next('table').find_next('class') 
for row in table.find_all('tr'):
    name=row.find_all("td")[0].text.strip()

    print(name)
```

The table data I am trying to extract is shown below:

[image: General]

**UPDATE:**
Here is the html element of the table from the above image:

```
<table class="tborder" cellpadding="6" cellspacing="1" border="0" width="100%" align="center">
<thead>
    <tr align="center">
     <td class="thead" width="150">Live Screenshot</td> 
      <td class="thead" width="130" align="left">Channel Number</td>
  <td class="thead" width="290">Now Playing</td>
      <td class="thead" width="170">Watching Options</td>
 

      
      
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr align="left">
        <td class="alt1Active" colspan="2" align="left" id="f13">
        
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
        <tbody><tr>
            <td class="alt1" width="20">
            
            <input type="image" width="130" height="90" src="http://213.163.74.154/ss2/tv1.jpg" onclick="open_tv1()"></td><td width="20"><center>
                <br></center></td><td height="80"><br><br><strong><img src="/images/uk.gif"><img src="/images/hd2.png"> Channel 1</strong> <br><br>
                
            
        
        


            </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody></table>
        
</td><td class="alt1" align="Center">


    

<div class="smallfont" align="left">
    <div style="clear:both">

    
<span class="smallfont"></span>

 <font size="2"><br><img class="inlineimg" src="http://www.kingmedia.tv/scripts/status.php?file=tv12.nsv" alt="12" border="0" title="12">&nbsp;<strong>Back Soon</strong><br>
    </font><iframe height="25" width="140" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" seamless="seamless" src="http://213.163.74.154:8080/tv1.xsl"></iframe><iframe height="25" width="80" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" seamless="seamless" src="http://207.244.98.215:8080/tv1.xsl"></iframe>
    <br><span class="smallfont"></span></div></div></td>
<td class="alt1" nowrap="nowrap">
<div align="right"><form name="menuformtv1">
<select name="menu1tv1">
<option disabled="">-- Server 1 --</option>
<option value="/buildmtv1s2.php">Watch in Winamp</option>
<option value="/webvlctv1s2.php">Watch in a Web Player</option>
<option value="/directlinktv1s2.php">View Stream URL</option>
<option disabled="">-- Server 2 (Backup) --</option>
<option value="/buildmtv1.php" selected="selected">Watch in Winamp </option>
<option value="/webvlctv1.php">Watch in a Web Player</option>
<option value="/directlinktv1.php">View Stream URL</option>

</select>

    <br><br><strong><a href="/home/payments.php">Subscribe to Unlock</a></strong>


</form></div><br>
 </td>
    <!----> 
        
    </tr>
</tbody>
<tbody>
    <tr align="left">
        <td class="alt1Active" colspan="2" align="left" id="f6">
        
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
        <tbody><tr>
            <td class="alt1" width="20">
            
            <input type="image" width="130" height="90" src="http://213.163.74.154/ss2/tv2.jpg" onclick="open_tv2()"></td><td width="20"><center>
                <br></center></td><td height="80"><br><br><strong><img src="/images/uk.gif"><img src="/images/hd2.png"> Channel 2</strong> <br><br>
                
            
        
        


            </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody></table>
        
</td><td class="alt1" align="Center">


    

<div class="smallfont" align="left">
    <div style="clear:both">

    
<span class="smallfont"></span>

 <font size="2"><br><img class="inlineimg" src="http://www.kingmedia.tv/scripts/status.php?file=tv9.nsv" alt="9" border="0" title="9">&nbsp;<strong>Back Soon</strong><br>
    </font><iframe height="25" width="140" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" seamless="seamless" src="http://213.163.74.154:8080/tv2.xsl"></iframe><iframe height="25" width="80" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" seamless="seamless" src="http://207.244.98.215:8080/tv2.xsl"></iframe>
    <br><span class="smallfont"></span></div></div></td>
<td class="alt1" nowrap="nowrap">
<div align="right"><form name="menuformtv2">
<select name="menu1tv2">
<option disabled="">-- Server 1 --</option>
<option value="/buildmtv2s2.php">Watch in Winamp</option>
<option value="/webvlctv2s2.php">Watch in a Web Player</option>
<option value="/directlinktv2s2.php">View Stream URL</option>
<option disabled="">-- Server 2 (Backup) --</option>
<option value="/buildmtv2.php" selected="selected">Watch in Winamp </option>
<option value="/webvlctv2.php">Watch in a Web Player</option>
<option value="/directlinktv2.php">View Stream URL</option>

</select>

    <br><br><strong><a href="/home/payments.php">Subscribe to Unlock</a></strong>


</form></div><br>
 </td>
    <!--<input type="image" src="/images/gs.gif" onClick="open_win2()" /><br>
<br><a href="/home/showthread.php?goto=newpost&amp;t=4"><img src=/images/wtn.gif align=right border=0></a>-->   
        
    </tr>
</tbody>
<tbody>
    <tr align="left">
        <td class="alt1Active" colspan="2" align="left" id="f17">
        
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
        <tbody><tr>
            <td class="alt1" width="20">
            
            <input type="image" width="130" height="90" src="http://213.163.74.154/ss2/tv3.jpg" onclick="open_tv3()"></td><td width="20"><center>
                <br></center></td><td height="80"><br><br><strong><img src="/images/uk.gif"><img src="/images/hd2.png"> Channel 3</strong> <br><br>
                
            
        
        


            </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody></table>
        
</td><td class="alt1" align="Center">


    

<div class="smallfont" align="left">
    <div style="clear:both">

    
<span class="smallfont"></span>

 <font size="2"><br><img class="inlineimg" src="http://www.kingmedia.tv/scripts/status.php?file=tv13.nsv" alt="13" border="0" title="13">&nbsp;<strong>Back Soon</strong><br>
    </font><iframe height="25" width="140" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" seamless="seamless" src="http://213.163.74.154:8080/tv3.xsl"></iframe><iframe height="25" width="80" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" seamless="seamless" src="http://207.244.98.215:8080/tv3.xsl"></iframe>
    <br><span class="smallfont"></span></div></div></td>
<td class="alt1" nowrap="nowrap">
<div align="right"><form name="menuformtv3">
<select name="menu1tv3">
<option disabled="">-- Server 1 --</option>
<option value="/buildmtv3s2.php">Watch in Winamp</option>
<option value="/webvlctv3s2.php">Watch in a Web Player</option>
<option value="/directlinktv3s2.php">View Stream URL</option>
<option disabled="">-- Server 2 (Backup) --</option>
<option value="/buildmtv3.php" selected="selected">Watch in Winamp </option>
<option value="/webvlctv3.php">Watch in a Web Player</option>
<option value="/directlinktv3.php">View Stream URL</option>

</select>

    <br><br><strong><a href="/home/payments.php">Subscribe to Unlock</a></strong>


</form></div><br>
 </td>
    <!--<input type="image" src="/images/gs.gif" onClick="open_win3()" /><br>
<br><a href="/home/showthread.php?goto=newpost&amp;t=8"><img src=/images/wtn.gif align=right border=0></a>-->   
        
    </tr>
</tbody>
<tbody>
    <tr align="left">
        <td class="alt1Active" colspan="2" align="left" id="f9">
        
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
        <tbody><tr>
            <td class="alt1" width="20">
            
            <input type="image" width="130" height="90" src="http://213.163.74.154/ss2/tv4.jpg" onclick="open_tv4()"></td><td width="20"><center>
                <br></center></td><td height="80"><br><br><strong><img src="/images/canada.gif"><img src="/images/hd2.png"> Channel 4</strong> <br><br>
                
            
        
        


            </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody></table>
        
</td><td class="alt1" align="Center">


    

<div class="smallfont" align="left">
    <div style="clear:both">

    
<span class="smallfont"></span>

 <font size="2"><br><img class="inlineimg" src="http://www.kingmedia.tv/scripts/status.php?file=tv3.nsv" alt="3" border="0" title="3">&nbsp;<strong>TSN 2 HD</strong><br>
    </font><iframe height="25" width="140" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" seamless="seamless" src="http://213.163.74.154:8080/tv4.xsl"></iframe><iframe height="25" width="80" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" seamless="seamless" src="http://207.244.98.215:8080/tv4.xsl"></iframe>
    <br><span class="smallfont"></span></div></div></td>
<td class="alt1" nowrap="nowrap">
<div align="right"><form name="menuformtv4">
<select name="menu1tv4">
<option disabled="">-- Server 1 --</option>
<option value="/buildmtv4s2.php">Watch in Winamp</option>
<option value="/webvlctv4s2.php">Watch in a Web Player</option>
<option value="/directlinktv4s2.php">View Stream URL</option>
<option disabled="">-- Server 2 (Backup) --</option>
<option value="/buildmtv4.php" selected="selected">Watch in Winamp </option>
<option value="/webvlctv4.php">Watch in a Web Player</option>
<option value="/directlinktv4.php">View Stream URL</option>

</select>

    <br><br><strong><a href="/home/payments.php">Subscribe to Unlock</a></strong>


</form></div><br>
 </td>
    <!--<input type="image" src="/images/gs.gif" onClick="open_win4()" /><br>
<br><a href="/home/showthread.php?goto=newpost&amp;t=8"><img src=/images/wtn.gif align=right border=0></a>-->   
        
    </tr>
</tbody>
<tbody>
    <tr align="left">
        <td class="alt1Active" colspan="2" align="left" id="f8">
        
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
        <tbody><tr>
            <td class="alt1" width="20">
            
            <input type="image" width="130" height="90" src="http://213.163.74.154/ss2/tv5.jpg" onclick="open_tv5()"></td><td width="20"><center>
                <br></center></td><td height="80"><br><br><strong><img src="/images/canada.gif"><img src="/images/hd2.png">Channel 5</strong> <br><br>
                
            
        
        


            </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody></table>
        
</td><td class="alt1" align="Center">


    

<div class="smallfont" align="left">
    <div style="clear:both">

    
<span class="smallfont"></span>

 <font size="2"><br><img class="inlineimg" src="images/icons/status.php.png" alt="test" border="0" title="test">&nbsp;<strong>TSN 3 HD</strong><br>
    </font><iframe height="25" width="140" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" seamless="seamless" src="http://213.163.74.154:8080/tv5.xsl"></iframe><iframe height="25" width="80" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" seamless="seamless" src="http://207.244.98.215:8080/tv5.xsl"></iframe>
    <br><span class="smallfont"></span></div></div></td>
<td class="alt1" nowrap="nowrap">
<div align="right"><form name="menuformtv5">
<select name="menu1tv5">
<option disabled="">-- Server 1 --</option>
<option value="/buildmtv5s2.php">Watch in Winamp</option>
<option value="/webvlctv5s2.php">Watch in a Web Player</option>
<option value="/directlinktv5s2.php">View Stream URL</option>
<option disabled="">-- Server 2 (Backup) --</option>
<option value="/buildmtv5.php" selected="selected">Watch in Winamp </option>
<option value="/webvlctv5.php">Watch in a Web Player</option>
<option value="/directlinktv5.php">View Stream URL</option>

</select>

    <br><br><strong><a href="/home/payments.php">Subscribe to Unlock</a></strong>


</form></div><br>
 </td>
    <!--<input type="image" src="/images/gs.gif" onClick="open_win5()" /><br>
<br><a href="/home/showthread.php?goto=newpost&amp;t=5"><img src=/images/wtn.gif align=right border=0></a>-->   
        
    </tr>
</tbody>
<tbody>
    <tr align="left">
        <td class="alt1Active" colspan="2" align="left" id="f11">
        
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
        <tbody><tr>
            <td class="alt1" width="20">
            
            <input type="image" width="130" height="90" src="http://213.163.74.154/ss2/tv6.jpg" onclick="open_tv6()"></td><td width="20"><center>
                <br></center></td><td height="80"><br><br><strong><img src="/images/usa.gif"><img src="/images/hd2.png"> Channel 6</strong> <br><br>
                
            
        
        


            </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody></table>
        
</td><td class="alt1" align="Center">


    

<div class="smallfont" align="left">
    <div style="clear:both">

    
<span class="smallfont"></span>

 <font size="2"><br><img class="inlineimg" src="images/icons/status.php.png" alt="test" border="0" title="test">&nbsp;<strong>ESPN HD</strong><br>
    </font><iframe height="25" width="140" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" seamless="seamless" src="http://213.163.74.154:8080/tv6.xsl"></iframe><iframe height="25" width="80" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" seamless="seamless" src="http://207.244.98.215:8080/tv6.xsl"></iframe>
    <br><span class="smallfont"></span></div></div></td>
<td class="alt1" nowrap="nowrap">
<div align="right"><form name="menuformtv6">
<select name="menu1tv6">
<option disabled="">-- Server 1 --</option>
<option value="/buildmtv6s2.php">Watch in Winamp</option>
<option value="/webvlctv6s2.php">Watch in a Web Player</option>
<option value="/directlinktv6s2.php">View Stream URL</option>
<option disabled="">-- Server 2 (Backup) --</option>
<option value="/buildmtv6.php" selected="selected">Watch in Winamp </option>
<option value="/webvlctv6.php">Watch in a Web Player</option>
<option value="/directlinktv6.php">View Stream URL</option>

</select>

    <br><br><strong><a href="/home/payments.php">Subscribe to Unlock</a></strong>


</form></div><br>
 </td>
    <!--<input type="image" src="/images/gs.gif" onClick="open_win6()" /><br>
<br><a href="/home/showthread.php?goto=newpost&amp;t=10"><img src=/images/wtn.gif align=right border=0></a>-->  
        
    </tr>
</tbody>
<tbody>
    <tr align="left">
        <td class="alt1Active" colspan="2" align="left" id="f4">
        
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
        <tbody><tr>
            <td class="alt1" width="20">
            
            <input type="image" width="130" height="90" src="http://213.163.74.154/ss2/tv7.jpg" onclick="open_tv7()"></td><td width="20"><center>
                <br></center></td><td height="80"><br><br><strong><img src="/images/world.gif"><img src="/images/hd2.png"> Channel 7</strong> <br><br>
                
            
        
        


            </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody></table>
        
</td><td class="alt1" align="Center">


    

<div class="smallfont" align="left">
    <div style="clear:both">

    
<span class="smallfont"></span>

 <font size="2"><br><img class="inlineimg" src="images/icons/status.php.png" alt="test" border="0" title="test">&nbsp;<strong>Live: Cricket</strong><br>
    </font><iframe height="25" width="140" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" seamless="seamless" src="http://213.163.74.154:8080/tv7.xsl"></iframe><iframe height="25" width="80" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" seamless="seamless" src="http://207.244.98.215:8080/tv7.xsl"></iframe>
    <br><span class="smallfont"></span></div></div></td>
<td class="alt1" nowrap="nowrap">
<div align="right"><form name="menuformtv7">
<select name="menu1tv7">
<option disabled="">-- Server 1 --</option>
<option value="/buildmtv7s2.php">Watch in Winamp</option>
<option value="/webvlctv7s2.php">Watch in a Web Player</option>
<option value="/directlinktv7s2.php">View Stream URL</option>
<option disabled="">-- Server 2 (Backup) --</option>
<option value="/buildmtv7.php" selected="selected">Watch in Winamp </option>
<option value="/webvlctv7.php">Watch in a Web Player</option>
<option value="/directlinktv7.php">View Stream URL</option>

</select>

    <br><br><strong><a href="/home/payments.php">Subscribe to Unlock</a></strong>


</form></div><br>
 </td>
    <!--<input type="image" src="/images/world.gif" onClick="open_win7()" /><br>
<br><a href="/home/showthread.php?goto=newpost&amp;t=3"><img src=/images/wtn.gif align=right border=0></a>-->   
        
    </tr>
</tbody>

</table>
```

**UPDATE:** I modified the code but it returns nothing. Here is my updated code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

URL = 'http://kingmedia.tv'
LOGIN_ROUTE = '/home/'

HEADERS = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.125 Safari/537.36', 'origin': URL, 'referer': URL + LOGIN_ROUTE}

s = requests.session()


login_payload = {
        'login': "bachoo786",
        'password': "abcde12345" 
        }

login_req = s.post(URL + LOGIN_ROUTE, headers=HEADERS, data=login_payload)

print(login_req.status_code)

cookies = login_req.cookies



r = requests.get(URL + '/forumdisplay.php?f=2')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
path = '/home/pi/'

tborders = soup.select('table.tborder')
tborders = [tborder.text for tborder in tborders]
#del tborders[0]

print (tborders)
```

Comment: hello dear Ahmed.B many many thanks for sharing this with us. One question - does it run now?! Look forward to hear from you

Comment: guess that youre having a closer look at this `
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
for div in soup.find_all(id=re.compile("^post_message")):
    print(div.get_text("\n", strip=True))
    `

Comment: '
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
for div in soup.find_all(id=re.compile("^post_message")):
    print(div.get_text("\n", strip=True))
    ' have a closer llok at this

Comment: Hi @zero I am still now able to run this

Comment: hi there - good day - is this a vbulletin!?

Comment: @zero I believe so. How can I tell if its not?

Comment: @zero i tried your code but it gives me : SyntaxError: invalid syntax in this line `for div in soup.find_all(id=re.compile("^post_message")):`